# In Vim my cursor doesn't return to correct place when going into insert mode

Tags: vim

In this line:

```
# include <unistd.h|>
```

( `|` represents cursor)

As shown in text above when I go from normal mode to insert mode the cursor doesn't return to after the `>` so I can't type after the text I already have.

This is just an example basically I can't get my cursor to be after the last character when in insert mode. Is it possibly due to a setting somewhere having been changed or something?

Answer (score 2):

You may find append mode suit this need than insert mode. For insert mode you would do a [ESC] [i] For append mode do a [esc] [a]